# How to center text in an SVG region

Tags: svg, icons, vector-icons

I'm attempting to center the text in my SVG region but am not succeeding. Does anyone have any insight on how to optimize this?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-label="Usa Mo" viewBox="0 0 70.389999 62.16">
    <g>
       <path tabindex="0" aria-label="Sainte Genevieve" fill="red" id="sainte genevieve" name="Sainte Genevieve" 
             d="m 57.466419,33.749401 
                  2.854,2.605 
                  -1.578,2.754 
                  -0.463,-0.343 
                  -0.441,0.418 
                  -1.953,-1.762 
                  -0.824,-0.796 
                  1.293,-1.417 
                  -0.982,-0.73 
                  1.582,-1.112 
                  0.512,0.383"
       > </path>
       <text font-family="Verdana" font-size="0.75" fill="blue">
           <textPath href="#sainte genevieve" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">Sainte Genevieve</textPath>
       </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe what you need is to use a different path for the text. You may choose one side for _sainte_ and another side for _genevieve_. Also this `id="sainte genevieve"` is not a valid id

Comment: @RobertLongson I did, to no avail.

Comment: @enxaneta My goal is for the the text to be centered; what do you mean by sides? Thanks for noting the invalid ID. The text is still shown though. How would that effect the spacing of the text?

Comment: can you edit your question and add an image of what you try to achieve?

Comment: @enxaneta I don't have a drawing. I just want the text to be inside the colored region and right side up.

Answer (score 1):

The OP is commenting:

> I just want the text to be inside the colored region and right side up.

In this case you don't need to use a textPath. You need to get the center of the path. For this you first get the bounding box of the path: `let bb = thePath.getBBox()`

Next you get the center of the path:

```
let x = bb.x + bb.width/2;
let y = bb.y + bb.height/2;
```

Finally you set the x and y attributes of the text as x and y making shure that the text is centered around this point: `text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle"`

```js
let bb = thePath.getBBox();
theText.setAttribute("x", bb.x + bb.width/2);
theText.setAttribute("y", bb.y + bb.height/2);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:300px}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-label="Usa Mo"  viewBox="50 30 15 12">
 
       <path id="thePath" aria-label="Sainte Genevieve" fill="red" id="sainte_genevieve" name="Sainte Genevieve" 
             d="m 57.466419,33.749401 
                  2.854,2.605 
                  -1.578,2.754 
                  -0.463,-0.343 
                  -0.441,0.418 
                  -1.953,-1.762 
                  -0.824,-0.796 
                  1.293,-1.417 
                  -0.982,-0.73 
                  1.582,-1.112 
                  0.512,0.383"
       > </path>
       <text id="theText" font-family="Verdana" font-size=".75" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
            Sainte Genevieve
       </text>
</svg>
```

Observation: I've changed the viewBox of the svg element because I wanted to have thePath in  the center. You can change it back to what it was.